# What is the best way to return results similar to the input?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

In my database I am selecting from a field containing `Dillon Brookfield`. I tried searching for `brookfield` with the following statement thinking LIKE would select the data, but it didn't work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Reports] 
WHERE ([VisitorName] LIKE '%' + @VisitorName + '%' 
       OR [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber)
```

I record people who have been banned from a property along with their plate (if known), but if their name is not put in exactly it doesn't return the value. What would be the best way to return similar results?

Comment: The only trouble is, `LIKE` is working case-sensitive?

Comment: Ill try it... whether i search for Brookfield or brookfield, it does not come back.

Comment: do you mean `LIKE '%' + @PlateNumber + '%'`?

Comment: Are you using '%' before and after your search term? like so: `VisitorName LIKE "%brookfield%"`?

Comment: SELECT * FROM [Reports] WHERE ([VisitorName] LIKE '%' + @PlateNumber + '%' OR [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber)

No change. Did not return the value from the column 'Dillon Brookfield'

Comment: What did I do wrong with the statement?

Comment: Does VisitorName contain the PlateNumber - It seems that is two different pieces of information and should be in two separate fields.

Comment: Take a look at the question. someone reformatted the statement to view a little better. both fields are there

Comment: Could be a case sensitivity thing. Do you know what collation your db is using? select databasepropertyex('databasename', 'collation') sqlcollation;

Comment: Try commenting out the parameter and entering LIKE '%BROOKFIELD%' and see if you get the desired result ... I don't know if you can concatenate these wildcard characters (but I could be wrong).

Comment: `[VisitorName] LIKE '%' + @PlateNumber + '%'` >> Why compare the visitor name to a plate number? Typo? The first version of your question had `[VisitorName] LIKE @VisitorName`

Comment: What data type is your @PlateNumber? Is it CHAR or VARCHAR? it can make a different. Like these tests.   DECLARE @var NCHAR(20) = 'space';
SELECT '%'+@var+ '%';
SELECT IIF('space' Like '%'+@var+ '%', 1,0);

Comment: @JamesCasey. I am afraid I do not understand what you mean. I am not sure what sqlcollation is. ill have to google it.

Comment: @TT. You are correct, it was a typo, iv fixed it.

Comment: @DVT Both data types are varchar(50)

Comment: @bansi that fixed it., thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a comment, but there is code inside and the comment only allows one `@`.

What data type is your `@PlateNumber`? Is it CHAR or VARCHAR? it can make a difference. Like these tests.

```
DECLARE @char NCHAR(20) = 'space';
SELECT '%'+@char+ '%',IIF('space' Like '%'+@char+ '%', 1,0);
DECLARE @varchar NVARCHAR(20) = 'space';
SELECT '%'+@varchar+ '%',IIF('space' Like '%'+@varchar+ '%', 1,0);
```

The first SELECT will give you

```
'%space               %',0. -- there will be 15 blank character between space and %
```

The second SELECT will give you

```
'%space%', 1.
```

Comment: The data type is VARCHAR(50) When the server is up i can try it as NCHAR. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: When you CONCAT, if the variable is NCHAR, it will preserve the space as the length of the variable. (In the example above, if variable is of type NCHAR(50) it will be the "space" and then 45 blank character. On the other hand, if it is NVARCHAR(50), then it will be just "space".)

Answer (score 0):

Create fulltext index. Search names/addresses and other similar fields with fulltext search - it'll be faster and you can find all names - Dillon Brookfield vs Brookfield Dillon.